How to implement a custom unnest function in Datafusion
I am working with Datafusion and I would like to implement a custom unnest function but it is not working
An unnest function by definition takes one value and has the possibility to generate multiple rows.
> select unnest(make_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) as unnested;
+----------+
| unnested |
+----------+
| 1        |
| 2        |
| 3        |
| 4        |
| 5        |
+----------+

For some use case I am trying to implement a custom unnest but I keep running into this error
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Internal("UDF returned a different number of rows than expected. Expected: 3, Got: 6")


The implementation looks something like this. This is not the custom logic I need but just to illustrate the issue
    fn invoke(&self, args: &[ColumnarValue]) -> Result<ColumnarValue> {
        let args = ColumnarValue::values_to_arrays(args)?;
        let values = datafusion::common::cast::as_int32_array(&args[0])?;
        let mut builder = Int32Array::builder(args[0].len());

        values.into_iter().for_each(|value| {
            match value {
                Some(value) => builder.append_values(&vec![value, value], &vec![true, true]),
                None => builder.append_null(),
            }
        });

        Ok(ColumnarValue::Array(
            Arc::new(builder.finish()) as ArrayRef,
        ))
    }

